# Python3 Passwords gives me a loop

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, while-loop, infinite-loop

while making a script i got some weird beheiviour form the python3 interpreter
the bug is  simply this
i enter the right UserName and Password i am granted with an infinite loop that has no condition

```
def LoginAdmin():
    # 3 chances seulement ...
    LoginTrial = 3
    position=0
    AdminOK=0
    AdminCheck=[]
    PassCheck = open('Data_LoginAdmin', 'r')
    #lecture des lignes et mise en données les informations mdp et login
    for ligne in PassCheck:
        print(ligne, end='')
        words = ligne.split(":")
        AdminCheck.append(words)
    print(AdminCheck)

    PassCheck.close()
    LoginAdminAcces = True

    while (((LoginTrial != 0) or (AdminOK == True))):
        UserAdminName=input("Identification : ")
        if not UserAdminName.isalpha:
            LoginTrial = LoginTrial - 1
            print("Autentification Échouer essai restant : ", LoginTrial)
        elif UserAdminName != AdminCheck[0][0]:
            LoginTrial = LoginTrial - 1
            print("Autentification Échouer essai restant : ", LoginTrial)
        elif UserAdminName == AdminCheck[0][0]:
            while (((LoginTrial != 0) or (AdminOK == True))):
                UserAdminPass=input("Mot de pass : ") 
                if not UserAdminName.isalpha:
                    LoginTrial = LoginTrial - 1
                    print("Autentification Échouer essai restant : ", LoginTrial)
                elif UserAdminPass != AdminCheck[0][1]:
                    LoginTrial = LoginTrial - 1
                    print("Autentification Échouer essai restant : ", LoginTrial)
                elif UserAdminPass == AdminCheck[0][1]:
                    LoginAdminAcces = True
                    AdminOK=True
                    print(AdminOK)
                    print("Accès apprové ...")
    if LoginTrial == 0:
        print("Accès Refusé !!!")
        LoginAdminAcces = False
    return (LoginAdminAcces)
```

this is the file Data_LoginAdmin

```
Admin:AdminPass
```

if someone see why it will save my life ... kind of ...

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what is going on but here is a potential problem:

1. `UserAdminName == AdminCheck[0][0]` and you enter the last elif (presumably the right password)
2. `AdminOK` is set to `True` (presumably meaning that the password has been validated)
3. the condition of the while is true since `AdminOK` is true

I think the while loop should want `AdminOK` to be false, that way you loop around again when the password is not okay. Also, the `or` should be an `and`. So change the while loop to

```
while (((LoginTrial != 0) and (AdminOK == False))):
```

Et "Autentification Échouée" car c'est UNE autentification.

Comment: Also since AdminOK is a boolean you could just say `not AdminOK`.

Comment: Haha, I need more sleep too. That is definitely an AND not an OR. You want the user to have remaining attempts AND to not have already gotten the password.

Comment: well there is actualy no way for the user to actualy input the password if the user name is wrong, that part works, the second while actualy crash me down as the true false gets ignored for some reason